# Styling zest graph nodes and connections

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, zest

I wish to change some visual properties of nodes and connections. How better can it be done? I found that visual information is applied in model factory that is returned from `org.eclipse.zest.core.viewers.GraphViewer.getFactory()`. There are three factories and all are placed in internal package `org.eclipse.zest.core.viewers.internal`.

Is it good approach to override `org.eclipse.zest.core.viewers.GraphViewer.getFactory()` and return own factory that does all necessary styling actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is interface `org.eclipse.zest.core.viewers.ISelfStyleProvider` which solves my problem without hacking into zest internal structure!